# Is it possible to create a stackdriver alert that will alert when any K8 pods are down?

Tags: stackdriver

I have the following setup:

```
   K8 Ingress    -->  K8 Service  --> K8 Pods x n 
(GCP LB for SSL)      (NodePort)      (containing the application)
```

I can setup a stackdriver HTTPS uptime alert to notify when the site is down, but this will only alert when all n pods are out of action.

Is it possible to create a stackdriver alert that will alert when any of the n application pods are down?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should consider putting correct scaling in place so that you may altogether avoid the need to alert when n application pods are down. Additionally, it's best to alert on what symptoms your users experience (increased latency or errors) rather than on the underlying infrastructure. Since it might be okay if n pods are down temporarily, as long as user requests still get served.
That being said, if you're running in GKE you can alert on container uptime. From your question I'm assuming that's not the case, so you could either:
* Log your own uptime checks, create a logs metric and alert when it's under a certain threshold.
* Similarly, create a custom uptime metric and alert on that.
Note that I would avoid creating a custom metric and using metric absence as the alerting policy condition, so I didn't list that as an option.
HTH and thanks for using Stackdriver.

Comment: Thanks - let me clarify the setup: I am running on GKE, with a K8 deployment so the scaling is taken care of.

The issue that I had was that there was a lurking bug in the health check of the K8 pod, so that after some time the pod would fail to start.  This meant that over time (say over the course of a few days), I would lose pods and they would end up in CrashLoopBackoff.  I would only get alerted when all n failed.

I think it would be good to set an alert for when a K8 deployment has #available < #desired.